# Does SQL support redefining base-operators?

Tags: sql, syntax, user-defined-functions

Is it possible to (re-)define a base operator in SQL dynamically without re-writing the source?

For example to define something like

```
CREATE TYPE <type> [...]
```

which translates to a set of default statements. Or to redefine `CREATE`?

Is there any DMBS that can do this?

**UPDATE:**

Okay, choosing `TYPE` as part of the example was a bad idea. Sorry for the confusion.

What I would like to know is, is it possible to define something like:

```
CREATE NEW ENTITY <Name> WITH <Attribute,...>
CREATE NEW OBJECT <ObjectName> OF <EntityName> WITH VALUES <Attribute=Value,...>
```

This will then be translated to a set of standard-statements that create or update relations.

I want to evaluate a way to model RM/T using a relational-only DBMS.

Comment: Why do you need this? What is the use case?

Comment: A "type" and an "operator" are two completely different things. What exactly are you talking about. And for which DBMS (Postgres? Oracle?). What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Please see the update.

It's not for a specific DBMS, it's just an evaluation for a proof-of-work.

Comment: As far as I know there is no such thing in "SQL" (the standard). But e.g. Postgres does offer you something similar. Either through a new type or through domains (there are other DBMS also that support domains)

Answer (score 0):

Is this ORACLE DB? In ORACLE you can

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE <type> [...]
```

http://psoug.org/reference/type.html